# Gorm for batch deletion

Tags: go, go-gorm

Golang uses the Gorm framework for batch deletion. How to write this statement?

```
func DeleteUsers(id []int64) error {
    return db.Table("users").Delete(id).Error
}
```

After using the above method, all the data in the table will be cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the code as below to solve the issue.

```golang
func DeleteUsers(id []int64) error {
    return db.Table("users").Where("users.id", id).Delete(struct{}{}).Error
}
```